# Performing a URL redirect and rewrite in the same rule for an Azure Front Door ruleset

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I am working on a project that uses Azure Front Door as a reverse proxy, and needs to handle the following case.

For a request with the URL `mydomainname/assets/someassetname`, the request needs to have `/assets/` removed from the URL, and `mydomainname` should be redirected to `myotherdomainname` all whilst preserving `someassetname` in the pathname.

To try to address this case, I first created a ruleset with 1 rule containing both a redirect action (for redirecting to `myotherdomainname`) and a rewrite action (for removing `/assets/`), which prompted this error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBmvt.png)

I tested this with a variety of conditions (including no conditions at all), but this error persisted.

I then created a ruleset with 2 separate rules, one with a redirect action, and another with rewrite action
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB0BK.png). However, the rewrite rule did not work once I had done this.

- Changing the order of the rules did not change the outcome
- Checking "Stop evaluating remaining rules" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/23bkK.png) for each rule caused each to be run individually, but unchecking both checkboxes did not cause both rules to be run

Is there a way of being able to run both rules on a request?

Comment: Same issue with me as well. Did you manage to solve it ?